# YOSYS simulating a combinatorial circuit with a specific input

Tags: simulation, circuit, yosys

I have a very simple combinatorial circuit written in .blif, such as:

.model circuit 
.inputs a b 
.outputs c 
.names a b c 
11 1 
.end

Now I'd like to simulate it with yosys, and I'd like to specify the input. Basically, I am trying to replicate the simulating command from SIS, which would be "simulate 0 1" and would give as a result "Output: 0". However, it seems from the documentation that I can only simulate cirucits with clock modules. Is there a way to specify that I only want the combinatorial behaviour of the circuit?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval`:

```
eval -set a 0 -set b 1
```

or if you want the full truth table:

```
eval -table a,b
```